# Java Swing panel sometimes not rendered correctly on a .Net container issue on Windows 10

Tags: .net, swing, windows-10, awt, jnbridge

We are facing issue with our desktop Application.

In our application we have a .net container panel (a parent panel) and then we have a child panel which is developed in Java Swing, AWT and Applet. This child panel is rendered on that parent panel ( i.e .net container window), sometimes this panel is not rendered in its correct position which is expected to inside the parent panel but sometimes it is rendered as an independent panel and pops out to Top Left corner of the screen.

We are using JNBridge for rendering Java component on .Net component.

We are facing this issue only on windows 10, it always works fine and rendered correctly on Windows 7.

This issue happens once out of 5 times and the flow application never breaks (i.e. we can save the work which we are currently doing).

The desktop Application which we are using is on Java 6.

We tried to upgrade and downgrade the JRE respectively to 6,7 & 8 but still the issue is reproducible.

It is not possible currently for us to migrate the whole desktop application to Java 8 or higher version. Some of our customers recently moved from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Comment: I would post your question at the support forum of JNBridge.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.